# ¿Como leer el resultado de ajax con c#?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo este codigo que me hace una consulta una accion de mi controlador, el cual me devuelve una lista en JSON

```
function CargPregRegist(valor) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("CargPregTipo")',
        data: "tipo=" + valor,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {

            }
        }
    });
}
```

lo que tengo pensado hacer es capturar el resultado de data pero con c# para así poder hacer una consulta con razor, alguien sabe como puedo leer ese data con c#?????
estoy trabajando con asp.net mvc 5

parte de lo que tengo planteado hacer es esto

```
@foreach (var m in t)
                    {
                        if (Model.Sto_TipoAlertas_Preguntas.lol(m.CodigoInterno1).TipoAlerta1 > 0)
                        {
                            <option value='@m.CodigoInterno1' selected>@m.DetallePregunta1</option>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <option value='@m.CodigoInterno1'>@m.DetallePregunta1</option>
                        }
                    }
```

lo que tiene que hacer esta parte del codigo seleccionar las que si cumple y mostrar en una lista separada 
ahora en donde esta el 0 es lo que voy a remplazar por la forma en como obtenga el resultado de ajax

Comment: Creo que hay un poco de confusión, el ciclo al ejecutar la llamada Ajax sería el siguiente: `AjaxRequest --> Controller --> View`, bajo este contexto, en el ajax debes enviar el valor, recibirlo en el Controller y luego regresar una vista o vista parcial

Comment: la cuestión es que no puedo devolver una vista parcial, estoy trabajando con un componente el cual no me lo permite trabajar con vista parciales, necesito hacer de alguna forma obtener el resultado de esa acción para manejar lo de forma inmediata

Comment: El punto es que una llamada Ajax, sí o sí va a un Controller, por lo tanto, entonces en el Controller deberás regresar un objeto diferente a una vista, puede ser un json, o el dato que quieras

Answer (score 0):

Agregas el código similar a esto:

```
if (data){
  for(i in data) {
     $("#id_select").append("<option value=" + data[i].CodigoInterno1 +
       ">" + data[i].DetallePregunta1 + "</option>");
   }
}
```

en la vista creas tu select:

```
<select id="id_select">
   <option value="0">[--Seleccione un Nombre--]</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pudiera ayudarte retornar el resultado en un string con formato html y asignarlo al  con jquery. Desde el metodo de C# puedes hacer la validacion que necesitas y de esta manera solo envias el contenido que necesitas mostrar a tu vista para asignarlo al

Te dejo un ejemplo que espero sea de tu ayuda

Codigo C# donde se formatea la respuesta:

```
var lstHtml= new StringBuilder();
                lstHtml.Append("<option selected='selected' value='-1'>-- Seleccionar --</option>");

                lstHtml.Append(string.Join(string.Empty, lista.Select(x =>
                string.Format("<option value='{0}'>{1}</option>",
                x.Id,
                x.Descripcion
                )).ToList()));
                comboHtml = lstHtml.ToString();
```

Codigo respuesta Ajax:

```
if (data) {
       $("#id_select").html(data.comboHtml);
        }
```